# stipulated time in processbuilder java

Tags: java

It's possible to stipulated time when run a command in with ProcessBuilder? Somelike this:

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "dir /s");
 Process p = builder.start();
```

This code can be stay running for a long time, I want to delimited for 1 second, for example. I think in put inside some thread and after this time destroy the process, but, it's possible to force some time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Process p = builder.start();
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(someTime); // Whatever time you want to wait
if (p.isAlive()) p.destroyForcibly();
```

You can't force it through the Process API

Answer (score 1):

You can start the process in a separate thread, sleep 1 second then you can kill the process.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "dir /s");
        Process p = builder.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        p.destroy();
    }
}).start();
```